# 2x2 macaroni pieces

Tags: design, piece-usage

I don't own any of the [brick, round corner 2 x 2 macaroni](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3063&in=S)  pieces. If you make a circle with them, can you fit a 2x2 round snugly within that circle?

Answer (score 8):

Yes it fits as well as you'd expect. same as any adjacent brick, so there's not much friction if you want to slide it up and down like a piston.

[image: 2x2 circle inside macaroni]